# cannot GET/ error message with body parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am very new to node so please excuse the simplicity but I don't believe I am grasping the fundamentals. I am trying to submit a form using bodyparser and I am receiving the error message: Cannot GET /newpoll?pollName=&option1=&option2=&submitButton= after I submit.

server.js

```
 'use strict';

 var express = require('express');
 var routes = require('./app/routes/index.js');
 var session = require('express-session');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 var app = express();


 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 routes(app, passport);

 var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
 app.listen(port,  function () {
   console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
 });
```

index.js
       'use strict';

```
  var path = process.cwd();
  var ClickHandler = require(path +  '/app/controllers/clickHandler.server.js');   
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function (app, passport) {

app.route('/newpoll')
    .post(isLoggedIn, bodyParser, function(req, res) {
        //console.log(req.pollName);
        console.log(req.option1);
        console.log(req.option2);

    });

 };
```

form action="/newpoll". I tried without the bodyparser variable in the router but it wasn't recognizing the variable, I thought it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint `/newpoll` doesn't exist for GET requests, you must make a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request in order to access the data, but, if you want access the data using GET requests, you can create a route using the [get](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD) method:

```
app.route('/newpoll')
  .get(isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.query);
  })
  .post(isLoggedIn, bodyParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
  })
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, but I don't use GET in my code, I use POST. correct?

Comment: soooo how does that help? There is nothing to change to solve the problem.

Comment: You don't need to change anything, you just need to send a POST request, instead of a GET request. Or you can create the GET method and access the data using req.query. Check my update @andrewgi

Comment: Ok got it, appreciate the help!

Comment: @andrewgi Any time! :)